# Encoding Struct directly gives different output than encoding variables of struct in spread out manner

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, abi, ethers.js

The output of both of these functions are different why?
How to make them equal. I am trying to use this in EIP712 signature checking. But the returned address doesn't match. It seems like encoding struct directly is done in some different manner than when done manually.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
pragma abicoder v2;



contract testabi {

    struct DATA {
        address a1;
        uint256 num;
        bytes nom;
    }

    bytes32 constant public DATA_TYPEHASH = keccak256("DATA(address a1,uint256 num,bytes nom)");


    DATA data1 = DATA(0x782DDbeBcCA0aC1952e6f8CD525f707B4e2B3077, 100, "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011170000000000000000000000000420000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");

    function encodeDecode1() public view returns(bytes32 ) {
            return keccak256(abi.encode(
            DATA_TYPEHASH,
            data1
        ));
    }

    function encodeDecode2() public view returns(bytes32 ) {
            return keccak256(abi.encode(
            DATA_TYPEHASH,
            data1.a1,
            data1.num,
            keccak256(data1.nom)
        ));
    }

  
}
```

```
JS code for generating signature

  const signature = await wallet._signTypedData(
    domain,
    {
      DATA: [
        { name: 'a1', type: 'address' },
        { name: 'num', type: 'uint256' },
        { name: 'nom', type: 'bytes' }
      ]
    },
    data
  )
  return signature
}
```